# Give a score to a sequence of numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

I have to give a score [0..100] to some number sequences made of number in the set {1..100}. Let me give you some examples:

> ```
>  1. [40, 40, 40, 40, 50, 55]
>  2. [73, 76, 80, 82]
>  3. [20, 20, 13, 13, 13, 13]
>  4. [8, 9, 8, 12, 13, 12]
>  5. [28, 28, 33, 30, 33, 30]
> ```

**Scoring parameters:**

- The sequence must be increasing to score better. Eg: in the following example 1 is better than 2. 3 is the worst one. (Stronger constraint)

> ```
>  1. [40, 41, 42, 45]
>  2. [40, 41, 45, 42]
>  3. [45, 42, 41, 40]
> ```

- A sequence is better than another if difference between numbers is very low. The lower, the better. Eg: in the following example 1 is better than 2.

> ```
>  1. [40, 41, 42, 45]
>  2. [0, 15, 30, 45]
> ```

**Some attempts:**

- Checking first element and last. When the second is higher then the first: the higher the difference, the higher the score.
- Standard Deviation gives interesting results, but still not excellent (previous sequence is sorted in this way)

**Scenario**

Let me explain the context, because I understand it doesn't have so much sense what I've been asking. A number in a sequence represents the current percent amount of requested items of an online shop (you don't know how many items are actually for sale).

For example `[0,50,51,100]` means that at time 1 nobody bought this item, at time 2 50% of this product was sold, and so on... Let's say previous sequence was real. The sequence is calculated in a interval of 2 minutes: this means that at least 100 elements were sold in 8 minutes!

Let's consider now the very similar sequence `[0,50,50,100]`: only one number changes, but this is not as good as previous one, because the shop is probably selling only 2 items and 8 minutes to sell 2 items is not so exceptional.

Which function can I use to optimize the scoring?

Comment: Your parameters are inconsistent. 13, 13, 13, 13 is better than 12, 13, 14, 15, since the differences are lower, but 12, 13, 14, 15 is better than 13, 13, 13, 13 since it is increasing. You have to decide what you really want, before you can ask for a function that does what you want.

Comment: You are right. Being increasing is a stronger condition than having lower differences.

Comment: OK; how much stronger? Is 10, 20, 40, 80 better than 10, 11, 13, 12? You really need to think through lots of possibilities and decide how to rank them before you can devise a function that does what you want it to do. Look at the 24 different ways to arrange 1, 2, 3, 4; how do order them from best to worst? How does 4, 1, 2, 3 compare to 4, 3, 2, 1?

Comment: I have updated the question explaining the scenario, now it should be much more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a pretty simple function to solve this task.

$(currentPercentage-firstPercentage)*\left\lvert minimumNotNullDifferencePercentage\right\rvert^{-1}$

For example:

> $[0,50,50,100] ⇒ (100-0)(50^{-1})$
>
> $[0,50,51,100] ⇒ (100-0)(1^{-1})$

Which works quite well applied to a real scenario.